# Is there a linux “cd” (change directory) command that can “cd” folders in grep style?

Tags: linux, cd

In Linux is there a way to `cd` folders in grep style?

For example you have directory named:

```
a__french_music___
```

I would like to write to terminal `cdgrep fre` and using Tab for autocompletion -->

```
cdgrep a__french_music___
```

Or to list all related alternatives if no a single directory exists.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but 'cd \*fre\*' will make you enter that folder. If multiple folders match you will get "too many arguments" in return instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not grep style, but [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) comes with case-insensitive autocompletion for the `cd` command.

You can type `cd fre`, then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to cycle through matches (only matches in the current directory will be shown), then the <kbd>Return</kbd> key when you are ready to select a match. If only one match is found, it will be automatically selected.

Comment: wow!!!! traditional scripts (bash commands) can run to this shell as .sh or are they incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

You might try some `readline` shortcuts in bash:

- type `cd *fre*` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> (by default). It will expand to `cd a__french_music___`. If there are multiple matching folders, it will put them **all** on the same line though.
- type `cd *fre` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (it auto-appends a `*`). If there is only one match, it will expand that onto the current line. If there are multiple matches, it will list them below like:

  ```
  $ ls *fre
  a__freaky/ a__french/ a__fresh/
  ```

Comment: this is much more complicated than oh myzesh solution... :)